# Which crankset standard will fit in my bottom bracket?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, compatibility

I have a bike with a press fit bottom bracket. Unfortunately, my existing crankset has too long of a spindle, and will not fit.

Measurements of note:

- bottom bracket shell width: 62 mm.
- outside bottom bracket width: 84 mm.
- bottom bracket spindle hole diameter: 24 mm.

Based on these measurements, I believe that I want a BB86 standard bottom bracket (supposedly it has some room for compatibility, so I am hoping that the 84 mm won't be an issue). Is this correct?

Comment: The number 84 is strange. What kind of bike is this?

Comment: It is a road bike.

Comment: Just use spacers if the spindle is too long?

Comment: I tried it with spacers, but my old crankset was too long and I couldn't get the play out. I feel like I probably could with a bb86 though, just wanted confirmation.

Comment: If the shell is really 62mm wide, you have one of the brand-specific proprietary shells. Really need to know the brand of bike. An off the shelf BB86 unit will do nothing for you.